# Mograph effect with geo-nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

how can I animate the scale and rotation of this geo-node staircase like mograph(C4D) is it possible?

with "mograph" i mean an animation that have a delay on each cube as it builds it self till the ground

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63310/animating-appearing-extending-strip-with-gaps https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82188/fill-along-the-front-of-a-path-of-an-svg https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19586/how-to-animate-the-disappearance-of-a-mesh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this node setup:

[image]

you get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this already helps a lot! that is what I want to achieve 
**[link](https://gifyu.com/image/Szhzy)**

Do you know the nodes that can offset the animation so it can build as you did. 
but animated as I did on that link. 

Thank you anyway, sir!

Comment: Hi Igor. Thanks for your link. Unfortunately you didn’t write this in your question. I answered as best as I could for your question. If my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. If you want „more“ animations please open a new question. Thanks.